# Python re.sub to capture groups unexpected behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, regex, replace

Consider following code:

```
import re

mystring = "\enquote {aaa} a \enquote {bbb}"
text = re.sub(r"\\enquote \{(.+)\}", r"\1", mystring)
print(text)
```

is outputing:

"aaa} a \enquote {bbb"

but I am acrually trying to achieve output of:

"aaa a bbb"

What have I misunderstood?

Background: I am trying to do some simple conversion from LaTeX format to general text, for which I need to replace LaTeX commands, but retain raw text itself (and sometimes do also some actual replacing). So how can I do group capture in python?

Comment: `text = re.sub(r"\\enquote \{(.+?)\}", r"\1", mystring)` <- notice the `?` in the regex

Comment: `re.sub(r"\\enquote {([^}]+)}", r"\1", mystring)`